# How to mine with NVidia GeForce GTX 560Ti on Linux?

Tags: gpu-mining, cryptonight

The questions is in title. Been surfing a bit, and I'm not aware of any software which allows mining with Nvidia GPU on Linux.

Answer (score 3):

We support with xmr-stak-nvidia all gpus from fermi up to the current available pascal generation.

Answer (score 1):

Your video card is old and may not be supported. Fireiceuk have released an xmr nvidia miner and may support it. You can try and install it https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak-nvidia. Lastly, this can be really problem for you when installing the required drivers for nvidia.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/KlausT/ccminer-cryptonight/releases

not positive if the 500 series is supported, but it's what I'm using for nvidia on linux currently